# Highchart rowsURL for several series

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to create chart using `rowsURL`. Here is an example:

```
data:
  rowsURL: "#{ build_chart_data_url(@obj) }",
  firstRowAsNames: false,
  enablePolling: true
```

It is OK when data returned from `build_chart_data_url` are something like this:

```
[
  [some_time, 4],
  [some_time, 6],
  [some_time, 10],
  ...
]
```

But I need have, for example, two series. Time for two series are the same (interval of my points is different).

When I try to do something like this:

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
```

My chart draws me two series but with the wrong time.

When I try to send something like this:

```
[
  #series 1
  [
    [some_time, 4],
    [some_time, 5]
  ],
  #series 2
  [
    [some_time, 6],
    [some_time, 7]
  ],
]
```

My Highchart draw nothing :(

Which data format I should send to use two series with `rowsURL`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is `some_time`? Is this what you are trying to get: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/06sohLze/3/?

Comment: multiple series has to defined like :  `series: [{ data: [1, 2] }, {data: [2,3] }, {data: [1,4]}]`

Comment: Real data example: => [[Mon, 24 Sep 2018 16:42:56 UTC +00:00, 176.88757384],
 [Mon, 24 Sep 2018 16:59:41 UTC +00:00, 178.99717367],
 [Mon, 24 Sep 2018 17:00:13 UTC +00:00, 178.99717367],
 [Mon, 24 Sep 2018 17:05:22 UTC +00:00, 180.12936827],
 [Mon, 24 Sep 2018 17:10:35 UTC +00:00, 182.22732555],
...

Comment: @prosto.vint Time needs to be in milliseconds since 1970. Either convert it as such before handing it to highcharts, or you have to convert it after.